# Usage of Docker --device flag inside a docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sgx, conclave

I am trying to load sgx driver inside a docker container, there is an option provided wherein we can provide this using --device flag , by executing `docker run --device /dev/sgx/enclave --device /dev/sgx/provision` , but we want to add this inside docker file and then get up the container.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that can be done in a Dockerfile.  A Docker image is just a filesystem image with some metadata that says how to run it.  What should happen if you push that image to a registry, and someone else downloads and runs it on their system?  (I suspect everything you're describing here needs to be done outside Docker entirely.)

Comment: Check linux-sgx repo, they have a Docker folder that contains everything you need.